# How to bind a Grid to a UserControl Property in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have a UserControl (let's call it "CustomControl") that acts as a simple toolbar for a grid. It contains only a button to open/close (it just changes it's visibility property) a Grid.

Like this:

```
<UserControl ....>
...
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btChangeState" Content="Change State" />
</Grid>
....
</UserControl>
```

And I have declared the DependencyProperty of a Grid like the following:

```
public Grid MyContent
{
    get { return (Grid)GetValue(MyContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyContentProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyContent", typeof(Grid), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

And my user control button has a simple handler to change the "MyContent" Grid Visible or collapsed:

```
if (MyContent.Visibility == Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible)
    MyContent.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
else
    MyContent.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
```

On my ViewPage, I am able to wire up the theUserControl.MyContent to theGrid in the constructor of the Page, but how can I do that in the XAML? I would like to do something like this:

```
<Page .....>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <cs:CustomControl x:Name="theUserControl" MyContent="{Binding theGrid}" />
        <Grid x:Name="theGrid" Height="200" Width="200" Background="Red" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ElementName`:

```
<cs:CustomControl x:Name="theUserControl" MyContent="{Binding ElementName=theGrid}" />
```